# Best type of Authentication to use for a custom Rest API?

Tags: php, api

We have to create a custom API written in PHP that will expose data to various stakeholders. These stakeholders will get access to functions like:

- getUserDetails($uid)
- getUserProducts($uid)
- getUserDevices($uid)

(and possibly more later on...)

My problem is that I am trying to decide on the best way to authenticate users of the API. I thought OAuth would be the way to go, but after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201431/what-exactly-is-oauth-open-authorization), I got the impression OAuth is only really used for things like logging in via Facebook or Gmail etc.

So my question is really this: What is the best type of authentication to use when creating a PHP API that external stakeholders can use? And is OAuth relevant in such a case?

Comment: Authentication *is* logging in, so I'm not clear on the distinction you're trying to make. OAuth is the standard for this, which is why Google/Facebook/Twitter/etc. all use it for authenticating requests to their APIs. You should too.

Answer (score 2):

If you want external stakeholders to call your APIs, just issue a pair of API key and API secret to each external stakeholder. You don't have to implement OAuth. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38054317/1174054) for the question *"[OAuth (Access Token) Vs API Key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38047736/1174054)"*.

Answer (score 1):

Oauth2 is the best solution

Comment: why is oauth the best solution?

Answer (score 1):

Oauth Is The Best  Option to ensure security in your REST Apps

You can use this library for implementing your own oauth system

https://github.com/bshaffer/oauth2-server-php

its very easy To Understand and