# Is it possible to secure my Java REST API with OAuth2 without Spring?

Tags: java, rest, oauth, oauth-2.0

I'm working on a server side application, what would be a REST API. Users would post data from their own hand made clients via this API to our own system. I would document the format of the data of course. But my question is, is it clever to implement the authentication with OAuth2 or am I better just going the SSL + Basic Auth route? If so, why? I googled a ton of posts and guides about OAuth2 and if it's not the client side they are handling, it is the Spring Security combination which I found rather hard to follow and questionable to implement since none of us in our company has used Spring framework.

Comment: OAuth2 and Spring aren't connected at the hips. You don't need to pull in Spring just to use OAuth2.

Comment: But yet most of the users opt to use the Spring Security + OAuth2 combination instead of just implementing the OAuth2 method. Why? I couldn't find any decent example or tutorial where the case wouldn't be this. And as an addition, all the examples used a login UI, where as I definetly don't want to use a UI to auth.

Comment: Spring is a popular framework. If you're already using Spring, you're obviously going to use Spring security and its OAuth2 implementation instead of rolling your own.

Answer (score 0):

As for "OAuth2 vs Basic Authentication", read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38047736/1174054) (OAuth (Access Token) Vs API Key) and the accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38054317/1174054).

[Spring Security OAuth](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/) is just one implementation. You can find some other implementations [here](http://openid.net/developers/libraries/). It should be noted that modern OAuth server implementations support [OpenID Connect](http://openid.net/connect/), but Spring Security OAuth doesn't. If your team is not familiar with Spring framework, there is no reason to use Spring Security OAuth. There exist many better implementations.