# Securing a REST API for multiple App types

Tags: rest, api, mobile, authorization, single-page-application

So, I've read a lot about different REST API authorization and authentication workflows over the past few days and figured I would reach out to see what folks thought. Here's my situation:

Mobile App:
The app does not require a user to login, but does make use of data provided by the REST API.

Single Page App:
A user logs into the SPA and can see/change data provided using AJAX calls to the REST API. The login is mainly restrict access to the web app and not the REST API.

API Testing via Postman:
I'm using Postman to test and debug the API routes / responses

Any thoughts on an effective scheme to ensure only authorized client/apps can access the REST API?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have a look at API Keys (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/8900124/1791065 for example)